# getting jquery like sytax from a node module

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I'm building my first node module, and I'm hoping to get something akin to jQuery

```
$(searchItem)
```

so the code could look something like

```
var $$ = require("myModule");

$$(search).doAction();
```

and the like, rather than

```
$$.doAction(search);
```

Is it possible to return a "root function" like this in a module? Are than any dangers in doing so?

------------------Update Laurent says it's doable as Underscore does it, and that it's safe, now for the how??----------------------------------

I've updated my code to my module starting with a self-referencing function (copied underscore)

```
(function(){
var fs = require("fs");
    console.log("starting");
    var root = this;
    var config =JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./config.json"));
    var $$ = function(obj){
        if(!obj){
            return config;
        } else {
            return obj;
        }
    }
}).call(this)
```

Then in my js page

```
require("myModule");
console.log($$("test"));
```

Hoping the the console would log "test", but unfortunately I'm getting `$$("test")` is not a function. 
------------------------------------ update -------------------------------------------
As jtblin pointed out in the answers below, exporting `module.exports = $$` works for outputing "test" as test is being passed to the function, but I can't chain methods as per the original example. Part way there though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you exported your function?

In your module:

```
module.exports = $$;
```

In another file

```
var $$ = require("myModule");
console.log($$("test"));
```

Comment: Nice wine jtblin, I tried your suggestion, and it didn't work at first, but in my module, I start with `var $$ = function(){...`, and then `module.exports = $$`, that works for returning "test", but it doesn't allow me to chain my methods, as the original example `$$(search).doAction()`. I triedmaking an object of $$ `var $$ ={...`, but then I can't get the "test" because $$ is no longer a function.

Comment: To chain methods, you just need to `return this` at the end of the $$ function.

Comment: You will need to create functions on the $$ prototype as well.

Comment: Thanks jtblin, can you update your answer with how you mean I should use "return this"? In my example, you can see I'm returning obj, or returning config. Obviously, I've only got one return statement. If I `return this`, I'm getting undefined on my console log, where I would have at least expected to get function. I'll have to look deeper into how to use prototype.

Comment: Ignore my stupidity on the last comment, I was forgetting to return from the inner methods.

Answer (score 2):

[Underscore](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore) is one of the most widely used node.js modules and it does exactly that, so it's pretty safe.

Comment: Thanks Laurent, I installed the underscore npm module and looked at the source, then tried to implement the a self-referring function in my module, the same way I've described above, but I get "object is not a function" when I try `$("test")`. I've updated my example above. Thanks for sharing that you feel it is safe, now just how do I accomplish the task?